# How to wrap data into an observable in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a user service that returns an email address of the logged in user from `localStorage`. I need to create a function that will pass that email address like an observable data and listen for changes in the `app.component` in order to show that email address for the logged in user in the top menu which is in the `app.component.html`

I have such function for returning a regular data from `localhost`:

```
getUser(){    
   this.userEmail = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")).name;
}
```

Comment: it's not clear what you want, but if you simply want to wrap email in observable do this  `Observable.of(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")).name)`

Comment: I want to receive user name in app.component like this ngOnInit(){
    this.authService.getUser().subscribe(data=>{
      this.userEmail = data;
      
    });

  }

Comment: see my answer then

Comment: I have an error 'property subscribe doesn't exist on type void;

Comment: did you try the code I posted in my example? if yes, then create a plunker where show the minimal setup

Comment: yeah I found the error. thanks

Comment: hey, so did [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45097555/2545680) help?

Answer (score 4):

Just use [of operator](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-of):

```
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';

...
getUser(){    
   return of(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")).name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
  import {Observable} from "rxjs/Rx";

  getUser = () : Observable<any> =>{
    return Observable.create((obs: any) => {
       obs.next(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")).name);
       obs.complete();
    });
  }
```